# How can I repeat Javascript expression for elements with different class names

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple elements which each contain the same class name appended with a number, created dynamically depending on where in the html structure they appear, e.g. myclass-1, myclass-2, myclass-4. There could potentially (though unlikely) be unlimited class numbers.

I would like - in vanilla Javascript (no jQuery) - to add a single click function so that if the element contains any class-*n* except class-1 to toggle another class. I can do it individually, like this:

```
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("click", toggleClass);
function toggleClass(event){
if(event.target.classList.contains("myclass-2")){
    event.target.classList.toggle("another-class");
    }
}
```

I could repeat this code multiple times, changing "myclass-2" to "myclass-3" and so on. Is there a way to do this in one go, excluding myclass-1? N.B. I don't think it's possible to change "myclass-1" to another class name automatically on page load (or not to my limited Javascript knowledge, anyway).

If I was including "myclass-1" I could do something like this:

```
    let existingClass = document.getElementsByClassName("*[class^=\"myclass-\"]")
```

But that isn't suitable here because of my need to exclude "myclass-1".

Would it be a push function? I'm very much a JS beginniner and only know the very basics of the push function, with a 'console.log' output, which doesn't help me here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation - add a single click listener to the window. On click, if the target is a `myclass` and is not a `myclass-1`, toggle the target.

Use `:not(.myclass-1)` to exclude `myclass-1`.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('[class^="myclass"]:not(.myclass-1')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('another-class');
  }
});
```

```css
.another-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass-1">one</div>
<div class="myclass-2">two</div>
```